# Pull to refresh needs some adjustments

Tags: codenameone

I'm using pull to refresh which works most fo the time but it often goes down way too far with no refresh action.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXm_uEBOygs

```
cnt.addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadComponent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this on the simulator with this standalone test case:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Pull"); 

    hi.getContentPane().addPullToRefresh(() -> {
        hi.add(new Button("Pulled!"));
        hi.revalidate();
    });

    hi.show();
```

I'm guessing that's a bug that needs [filing](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/).